# HTML image map with pop ups. animated with jquery and fall back to css

Tags: jquery, html, css, dictionary

I am trying to build a image map with pop ups. I have found a good solution just using css and would like to animate the pop ups using jquery.

I know there are loads of jquery solutions online but I haven't found one that falls back to the css when javascript is turned off. Here is a fiddle with a basic example of the CSS version I want to animate.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/QJN6H/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just write your jQuery animation code to work on top of the css code you've already written then with no javascript you'll simply get the current results that you're getting from your css.

Comment: its that simple is it. I am always looking to deep into these things

Comment: I have had a play around [link]http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/QJN6H/8/ and It kind of works but it triggers it on all li a span elements, I want it to only set off the one relating to area hoverd over. any help appreciated

Comment: This will target the specific span within the 'a' tag currently being hovered over.

$("#map li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("span").fadeToggle("medium");
});